# SQLite で INSERT と UPDATE を一回で行う方法

Tags: python, sqlite

PythonでSQLite3を使用しています。

既存のDBに読み込んだDBのデータをマージしたいと思い、簡潔に記述する方法はないかと調べていました。
具体的には参考URLのように、プライマリキーが一致するものはUpdate、存在しなければInsertをしたいです。
SQLiteにはMERGE構文がサポートされていないのでしょうか？
サポートされていない場合、SQLの構文はどのようにしたらよいでしょうか？

参考URL:
[SQL MERGE文でINSERTとUPDATEを一回で行う](https://omachizura.com/2016/06/sql-merge.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLiteには以下のSQLがあるようです(実際に試したわけではありません)。
リンク先は「SQLiteリファレンス」です。

- データがあれば更新、無ければ追加するSQL文
  [on conflict do 句](https://sqlite-r.com/on_conflict_do)
- データがあれば置き換えて、無ければ追加するSQL文
  [replace into 文](https://sqlite-r.com/replace_into)

これらの違いが分かっていませんが参考になればと思い回答します

Comment: ありがとうございます。on conflict do 句はSqlite3 Ver3.24から実装なので、標準のPython実装のSqliteでは使用できないようです。replace into分で実装できました。ほかのデータベースの互換性確保のためにあると記述があるので、本来on conflict do 句が良いのだろうと思います。

Comment: replace intoは、プライマリーキーが一致した場合一旦削除して追加し直しだったと思うのでそこだけ注意が必要かもしれません。